# How to clean (destroy) Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 modal form content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter Bootstrap modal where I show some form elements. I'm trying to clean up all the form elements content on BS hidden/close but I'm doing something wrong since none of the code below works:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal').removeData();
})

$("#addNorma").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});
```

Maybe this "destroy" is for something else and I don't get it. Anyway [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/kk3xr15m/) is a fiddle where I show the problem:

- Open the modal and write something in any input
- Close the modal
- Open the modal again and you'll see the content

I want to avoid this behavior, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about simply [reseting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) a form to its original state, maybe it will work for you?

```
$("#addNorma").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kk3xr15m/1/